# Appending values to a vector in a function

Tags: r, vector

First off, here is my code:

```
count <- vector()
f1 <- function(x) {
  file <- read.csv(x)
  date <- grep(pattern = "lalala", names(file))
  file <- file[date]

  file.row <- unlist(file)
  num <- length(unique(file.row))
  count <- c(count, num)
}

files <- list.files(path="path/to/directory", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
lapply(files, f1)
```

I am trying to store an integer, num, into the count vector. However, calling this script gives me an empty count vector, so I tested to see what the count value was at every run of the function, and it's printing out the right values, except it seems like the count vector is reinitializing to an empty vector at the beginning of every run of the function. What is going on and how could I fix this?

Comment: The problem is that your function needs a return value. Btw, dynamically growing things is a bad idea.

Comment: "the count vector is reinitializing to an empty vector at the beginning of every run of the function"---this is how functions work in functional programming languages (such as R).

Comment: R is behaving like it should, read into [lexical scoping](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scopingl)

Comment: @plafort I think it's the product of the number of unique rows in columns containing "lalala" with the number of columns containing "lalala"... some simplification possible, but it's not just a one-liner.

Comment: I agree. OP will be left with `length(unique(unlist(file[names(file) %in% grep('lalala', names(file)),])))` too clunky and unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but Frank's right, you should just `return()` your count, and let the apply function do the appending. I switched to `sapply` so you should get a vector back instead of a list:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  file <- read.csv(x)
  date <- grep(pattern = "lalala", names(file))
  file <- file[date]

  file.row <- unlist(file)
  return(length(unique(file.row)))
}

files <- list.files(path="path/to/directory", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
count = sapply(files, f1)
```

Comment: This worked, but when I just type in count to see the values inside the vector, the entire pathname and the index are printed out in one line. I probably didn't make that clear enough so I'll give an example:

C:/path/name
                    1 
C:/path/name2
                    2..... and so on.

Comment: The result is a named vector. If you don't want the names just `unname()` the result.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is simply

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  file <- read.csv(x)
  date <- grep(pattern = "lalala", names(file))
  file <- file[date]

  file.row <- unlist(file)
  num <- length(unique(file.row))
  num ## implicitly return `num`
}

files <- list.files(path="path/to/directory", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
lapply(files, f1)
```

Note this (`lapply()`) will return a list so you might want to simplify it by using `sapply()` instead:

```
sapply(files, f1)
```

Note you don't need to call `return()` explicitly in `f1()` as this is already done for you.

Comment: @plafort Yes, although I often find it helps me looking at the code to see the object returned as I give it a name that means something to me. I know would have to parse `length(unique(file.row))` every time I read the code, but putting something like `nvars` or something equally informative, I would know what I intended to return. (Must admit to not having read and fully grepped exactly what the OP's code here is doing - I just reused `num` as the object to return).